# MS Accesss - where cluase with group by and having clause

Tags: ms-access, group-by, where-clause

Following is the part of data, in Access:

```
icode   soldQty rackQty      dt
---------------------------------------
14000   10      50       03/17/22 20:35
15000    1      45       03/17/22 15:35
16000    3      55       03/17/22 08:22
14000   30      48       03/18/22 14:05
15000   18      62       03/17/22 13:35
16000    3      47       03/17/22 15:23
14000    1      49       03/19/22 16:35
17000    1      49       03/17/22 15:13
14000   24      26       03/17/22 10:35
15000   10      33       03/17/22 20:37
```

There are more than 100 icodes, I am putting just 3 as an example.
I want to generate a Weekly (or between some dates) report based on a certain time period.
Say, a weekly report between 10:00 to 17:00 for 3 items, 14000, 15000 and 16000. The output, I am expecting is:

```
icode   soldQty rackQty
14000   54         74
15000   19        107
16000    4         96
```

Using this query, I am able to get the sum.

```
select icode, sum(soldQty), sum(rackQty) from sales 
group by icode having icode between 14000 and 16000 
order by icode
```

I am confused where to put the `where clause` so that I can have a condition for the
timing (10:00 to 17:00) constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
select icode, sum(soldQty), sum(rackQty) 
from sales 
where TimeValue(dt) between #10:00:00# and #17:00:00#
group by icode 
having icode between 14000 and 16000 
order by icode
```

Answer (score 2):

All the conditions should be placed in the `WHERE` clause.

The `HAVING` clause is used for conditions that contain aggregated values like `SUM()` or `COUNT()` and it is processed after the aggregation:

```
SELECT icode, 
       SUM(soldQty) AS total_soldQty, 
       SUM(rackQty) AS total_rackQty 
FROM sales 
WHERE icode BETWEEN 14000 AND 16000
  AND TimeValue(dt) BETWEEN #10:00:00# AND #17:00:00#
GROUP BY icode  
ORDER BY icode;
```